# Create sub stream in python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I create a "sub stream" in python. Let's say I have an file opened for reading. I want to return a file-like object that you can use to read only part of that file.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    start = 0x34
    size = 0x20
    return Substream(f, start, size)  # <-- How do I do this?
```

Seeking to 0 on this object should go to "start" on the `f` object. Further more reading past size should trigger eof behavior. Hope this makes sense. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick subclass of `io.RawIOBase` seems to do the trick, at least for my use case. I understand this is not a full implementation of the `io.RawIOBase interface`, but it gets the job done.

```
class Substream(io.RawIOBase):
    """Represents a view of a subset of a file like object"""
    def __init__(self, file: io.RawIOBase, start, size):
        self.file = file
        self.start = start
        self.size = size
        self.p = 0

    def seek(self, offset, origin=0):
        if origin == 0:
            self.p = offset
        elif origin == 1:
            self.p += offset
        # TODO: origin == 2
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unexpected origin: {}".format(origin))

    def read(self, n):
        prev = self.file.tell()
        self.file.seek(self.start + self.p)
        data = self.file.read(n if self.p + n <= self.size else self.size - self.p)
        self.p += len(data)
        self.file.seek(prev)
        return data
```

Use it like so

```
with open(filename) as f:
    print(Substream(f, 10, 100).read(10))
```

I wonder if this can be done on file descriptor level instead somehow...?